# How do I add google map in satellite on iframe

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe

I am adding a google maps iframe to my website, the problem is I want it to display as satellite view instead of street view. This is an example iframe for Antarctica:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d16858886.629529595!2d0!3d-75.05434995!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0xa4b9967b3390754b%3A0x6e52be1f740f2075!2sAntarctica!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1627212267326!5m2!1sen!2sin" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
```

I got the iframe by following [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-google-map-inside-html-page-without-using-api-key/) since I don't want to insert it using an API key.

How would I add a Google Map defaulting to satellite mode in an iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you click on "Share" in Google maps change map type to satellite.

Answer (score 0):

I bumped to that issue too while trying to embed to my WordPress website. Turns out you can actually reconfigure it by adjusting how the google maps screen looks before you hit "share".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).